# Unable to make a div tag visible from aspx.cs file on Button click event

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem enabling a div tag visible in the aspx.cs file. I was able to make it visible in the Page load event by setting the visible property to true but when i was doing the same in the Button click event it isn't working. The following is my div tag. I am not sure what I am missing here.

```
    <div id="ProcessingScreen" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <div style="position: fixed; z-index: 100001; left: 50%; top: 50%;"
            role="status" aria-hidden="true" runat="server">
            <div class="preloadBG" runat="server">
                <div class="loadingStyle" runat="server">
                </div>
                <div align="center" runat="server">Processing...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modalPopup" style="position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 10000; width: 100%; height: 800px;" runat="server">
        </div>
    </div>


My Button code:

<div class="row">
      <asp:Button ID="SubmitCode" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
       OnClick="SubmitCode_Click" />
</div>
```

My backend code looks like this:

```
 protected void SubmitCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessingScreen.Visible = true;
            string url = URIPathTextBox.Text;
            CheckStatus(url);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            dl.InsertOBLogs("Exception while Checking:", "Exception Message:" + exception.Message + " " + "Inner Exception Message:" + exception.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So where and what is in the backend code?

Comment: My backend code:                                                                    protected void SubmitCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessingScreen.Visible = true;
                string url = URIPathTextBox.Text;
                CheckStatusOfAPICall(url);
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                dl.InsertOBLogs("Exception while Checking the :", "Exception Message:" + exception.Message + " " + "Inner Exception Message:" + exception.InnerException);
            }
        }

Comment: <div class="row">

                    <asp:Button ID="SubmitCode" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="SubmitCode_Click" />
                </div>

Comment: how about setting a break point in the event and stepping through it? maybe there's an exception? how about removing the rest of the code from the button click event and only leaving the `ProcessingScreen.Visible = true;` line?

Comment: CheckStatus() routine better run real quick and fast - since until it is finished, then the whole web page will wait and NOT travel back down to the browser until ALL CODE behind is done. if you want the visible setting to take effect and show, then CheckStatus can not pause or case the code to wait. If checkstatus is going to take some time, then start it as a thread - and thus the code behind can exit. So any blocking code in codebehind will cause the whole web page to sit on the server until all code is done, the page goes down to client side, and your visible setting will take effect.